# TASM 16bit segment not supported

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, 16-bit, tasm

```
TITLE EXOR
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 

iamge db 'exor.bmp',0

.code

mov dx,[bp+4]
MOV AX,3d00h
int 21h

end
```

I'm trying to open a bmp file using assembly but this what happends when I tasm my asm file 
can you help me why this error occurs? 
I can tasm the asm but when I run it or tlink it this message is shown `Fatal: 16-bit segments is not supported in module exor.asm`

Comment: Missing the error totally here. What error do you get ?

Comment: I don't believe you can do `.model small` and then also do `.data` - _small_ implies no explicit segments.

Comment: It looks like you try to run 16bit DOS module on 64bit machine. When the CPU is switched to 64bit, addressing mode which uses 16bit registers, such as [bp+4], is no longer available.

Comment: Note: The instruction "mov dx,[bp+4]" get a word from SS:[bp+4], because the default segmentregister is SS for using BP as an adressregister. For to get the offset address of "iamge" just use "lea dx,iamge", or "mov dx,offset iamge". For 64 Bit Windows use DOSBOX.

Comment: @500 : it is perfectly legal to have .code and .data defined in a small model program. The compiled code and the linker will place the code and data in the same segment. Code will appear first and data will appear after.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

filename db 'test.bmp',0
filehandle dw ?
Header db 54 dup (0)
Palette db 256*4 dup (0)
ScrLine db 320 dup (0)
ErrorMsg db 'Error', 13, 10,'$'

CODESEG

proc OpenFile
; Open file
mov ah, 3Dh
xor al, al
mov dx, offset filename
int 21h
jc openerror
mov [filehandle], ax
ret
openerror:
mov dx, offset ErrorMsg
mov ah, 9h
int 21h
ret
endp OpenFile

proc ReadHeader
; Read BMP file header, 54 bytes
mov ah,3fh
mov bx, [filehandle]
mov cx,54
mov dx,offset Header
int 21h
ret
endp ReadHeader

proc ReadPalette
; Read BMP file color palette, 256 colors * 4 bytes (400h)
mov ah,3fh
mov cx,400h
mov dx,offset Palette
int 21h
ret
endp ReadPalette

proc CopyPal
; Copy the colors palette to the video memory
; The number of the first color should be sent to port 3C8h
; The palette is sent to port 3C9h
mov si,offset Palette
mov cx,256
mov dx,3C8h
mov al,0
; Copy starting color to port 3C8h
out dx,al
; Copy palette itself to port 3C9h
inc dx
PalLoop:
; Note: Colors in a BMP file are saved as BGR values rather than RGB.
mov al,[si+2] ; Get red value.
shr al,2 ; Max. is 255, but video palette maximal
; value is 63. Therefore dividing by 4.
out dx,al ; Send it.
mov al,[si+1] ; Get green value.
shr al,2
out dx,al ; Send it.
mov al,[si] ; Get blue value.
shr al,2
out dx,al ; Send it.
add si,4 ; Point to next color.
; (There is a null chr. after every color.)
loop PalLoop
ret
endp CopyPal

proc CopyBitmap
; BMP graphics are saved upside-down.
; Read the graphic line by line (200 lines in VGA format),
; displaying the lines from bottom to top.
mov ax, 0A000h
mov es, ax
mov cx,200
PrintBMPLoop:
push cx
; di = cx*320, point to the correct screen line
mov di,cx
shl cx,6
shl di,8
add di,cx
; Read one line
mov ah,3fh
mov cx,320
mov dx,offset ScrLine
int 21h
; Copy one line into video memory
cld ; Clear direction flag, for movsb
mov cx,320
mov si,offset ScrLine
rep movsb ; Copy line to the screen
;rep movsb is same as the following code:
;mov es:di, ds:si
;inc si
;inc di
;dec cx
;loop until cx=0
pop cx
loop PrintBMPLoop
ret
endp CopyBitmap

start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
; Graphic mode
mov ax, 13h
int 10h

; Process BMP file
call OpenFile
call ReadHeader
call ReadPalette
call CopyPal
call CopyBitmap

; Wait for key press
mov ah,1
int 21h

; Back to text mode
mov ah, 0
mov al, 2
int 10h

exit:
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
END start
```

this should work it has some function that will open the file, copy the file pal and print it on the screen

hope it helps